# Export datetime excel python

Tags: python, cx-oracle, temporary-files, xlwt

Can't export date.

```
import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
cur.execute('SELECT date, name from table')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row, array in enumerate(rows):
    for col, value in enumerate(array):
        sheet1.write(row, col, value)

name = "this.xls"
book.save(name)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Instead of 08/17/2020 it gives 44044. Name gives the correct

Comment: Maybe you should give some sample data instead of `cur.fetchall()`. For easier copying

Answer (score 0):

`44044` is `08/17/2020` in Excel.

44044 are the days from 0.0.1900 to 08/17/2020.

You need to change the format in Excel from number to date and it will show the correct date.

```
date_format = xlwt.XFStyle()
date_format.num_format_str = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
sheet1.write(row, col, value, date_format)
```

if you still expirience trouble try replacing the `value` with a datetime like this one:

```
import datetime
value = datetime.datetime.now()
```